# Excel Countifs based on cell containing text

Tags: excel

I have Column A that includes keywords I want to use to filter.

For example, some cells in column A include the keywords "Yes" and "Northeast Region" and I want to count the number that do.

What is wrong with this function?

=countifs(Contracts[Status], isnumber(search("Yes"), isnumber(search("Northeast Region")))

Comment: COUNTIFS() is in pairs `COUNTIFS(RANGE1,CRITERIA1,RANGE2,CRITERIA2)`.  Also it is `AND` not `OR`.

Comment: Also Search takes at least two criteria.  what to search and the range to search.

Comment: @Scott Craner But COUNTIF(S) can easily be adapted to work with "OR" statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the SUMPRODUCT() formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes",Contracts[Status])))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Northeast Region",Contracts[Status]))))
```

The `+` creates an `OR` situation.  If either is true it resolves to 1 and the SUMPRODUCT adds it to the total.

Comment: I will leave this here, but the formula given by @XORLX is better in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(COUNTIF(Contracts[Status],{"Yes","Northeast Region"}))`

Regards

Comment: I was unaware of this.  Though from what the OP had wouldn't it be `=SUM(COUNTIF(Contracts[Status],{"*Yes*","*Northeast Region*"}))` with the wildcards?

Comment: Ah, yes. Perhaps. Couldn't quite work out from the OP's description which was being sought. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question, would this then become a non CSE array formula, or would we still be able to use full column references with little detriment?

Comment: Yes - this does not require CSE, and so we can continue to use full column references with no detriment. Effectively, the SUM/array constant combination simply instructs Excel to perform (in this instance) two separate COUNTIFs, then sum the two results.

Comment: Well, I guess I learned my one thing today, time to go home.  Thanks.  It makes sense as I think about it.